# How do I add the salesdescription field in Nesuite Checkout 2.03

Tags: javascript, netsuite

How do I add the salesdescription from the item document to the cart line items in the Netsuite Checkout .ssp solution?  I can call the name, itemid, quantity, etc, using:

```
<%= item.get('_name') %> 
<%= item.get('itemid') %>
<%= line.get('quantity') %>
```

but for some reason <%= item.get('salesdecription') %> does not work.

I have been up and down through model.js and the .ss pages and I dont see where the API is pulled for the quantity, itemid, or name.

Comment: are you using suite commerce advanced?

Comment: No, this is a sitebuilder site.

Comment: did you add the field on your website content manager form for item and published the itmes?

Comment: I'm not certain the form that you are asking about. I went through the website content manager and did'nt see a form with that name.  Could you give me a little more direction as to what you mean?  The field does show and is set to display under setup/site builder/setup website/edit/(Cart Tab).

Comment: When you customize a standard item form You should see checkboxes  - "USE FOR MANAGER" and  "WEB SITE CONTENT MANAGER ONLY" , these might be checked for an existing standard one, customize and show the fields on form that you want to access.

Comment: My Bad for cart line items, you would see only SO line items field, you can really access item fields, try adding a custom line item field on SO that duplicates the value for this field either using a formula or user event.

Comment: Description is already a line item field on the sales order, do I need to do anything else with it?

Comment: the internal id of that field is description right ? try <%= item.get('salesdecription') %>. Make sure the value of sales description is pulled into that field via user event script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by updating from Sitebuilder 2.03 to Sitebuilder Denali (after reinstalling 2.03 from scratch, finding and following explicit directions from Netsuite from the suiteAnswers pages(Answer Id: 40454 if you have a login), and I still had the issue). If there was a work around for this in 2.03, I never found it.